# Making a .ttf file of a .png file

Tags: html, css, svg, fonts

Every website has some .png images like logo, icons and etc ..

I have an idea about it. that's creating a font of those images. I mean I can create a vector-image of my website's logo and convert it to a .ttf or .svg file (a font). Because a font has much less size than a png and I also can set it color, size, border and etc ..

so what do you think about my idea? Converting all pngs to a font is a good idea?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [font icons vs png icons](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12514236/font-icons-vs-png-icons)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take into account that fonts have some limitations such as that they can only be a single colour per image and that they are build up from vectors instead of pixels. There are probably not that many images that satisfy this requirement on your site.

Svg on the other hand does support what fonts lack and also has [pretty good browser support](http://caniuse.com/#feat=svg) so I would recommend using it if it doesn't have too many shapes (the browser has to convert it to pixels on the fly, which requires some processing) and it actually cuts down your image's filesize.
You can't really convert png files to svg files as the vectors are hard to deduce accurately from the pixel data. If you have the original image in a vector format like .ai (Adobe Illustrator) then you can use that to get your svg images.

On a sidenote, if you're interested in reducing your bandwidth even more, take a look at [webp](https://developers.google.com/speed/webp/) for a replacement for your pixel-based images. The browser support isn't that great through (only Chrome, Opera and Android), so you still have to use what you are currently using as a fallback type. It also takes some effort to implement it into your website.